# Calculating required power to run 2 modems in kWh

Tags: power, batteries, modem

I am an electronics newbie. I have two modems at home. One is DSL Ethernet modem provided by DSL provider and other is TPLink wireless router. I see they have written Voltage and Ampere written on their backs

```
DSL Modem:     12 V  0.8 A
TPLink Modem:   9 V  0.6 A
```

Now I am using `W = V . A` ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt#Definition)) to calculate Watts of these devices and I want to ask if I am doing this right?

I am trying to calculate how much power (kWh) these devices need so I may buy battery accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll correct the misconception about "power". kWh is NOT a unit of measurement for power, it's unit of measurement for energy!  For some reason, people in sore regions keep talking about electrical power when they mean energy.

Your first step in calculation is correct. When you multiply current with voltage, you get power. 
Your second step is not solveable because your premise is missing information. kWh is literally kW*h, that is to say power in kilowatts multiplied by time in hours. Energy is measured in joules and one joule is watt multiplied by second. One kilowatt-hour is 1000 W * 3600 s.

So how do you calculate the amount of energy you need for batteries? Well the simplest approximation is to multiply the power, which you got correctly, by the amount of time you want the devices to run. That information you need to decide for yourself.

In the following section, I'll go into details a bit.

First, the power you calculated with the formula you provided is the maximum power a device can consume. In normal operation, it will be less. Next, the voltage rating on the devices usually aren't very strict. You could probably run the 12 V device from 9 V or maybe even the 9 V device from 12 V. Specifics depend on the internal construction of the device, so some experimentation and research will be needed to determine if everything will be OK.

Next, there's the minimum voltage at which the device will run, which will often be below the nominal input voltage of the device. That is the voltage your battery will need t provide in order for the devices to work. This will be important if you plan to connect devices directly to a battery and need to pick a battery chemistry and configuration.

Comment: +1 for mentioning battery selection considerations. There is an entire topic in there about discharge curves and so on, though perhaps not in answering at OP's level of understanding.

Comment: thanks, because my modems are running 24/7 so I will use 24 hours into 3600.

Comment: @UmairAshraf: Why are you concerned about running your modems off battery power? Are you also going to run your computer off battery power? A battery-powered modem is no use if you have no power for your computer.

Comment: It's a pet project of mine to put modems over rechargeable batteries which will be charged by solar panel. The computers are laptops with working batteries.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are trying to connect your equipment to a uninterruptible power supply (UPS) of some kind.

For your purposes, real power (watts) is given by P [watts] = V [volts] × I [amps] ÷ efficiency [%].

You may take the efficiency of the average wall power adapter to be 90%. (The other 10% is wasted as heat.)

As AndrejaKo mentions, you then multiply the power consumption per second (watts) by the desired running time on battery supply (hours) to obtain a figure in kilowatt hours (kWh).

Battery stored energy E [kWh] = P [watts] × desired run time [hours] ÷ 3,600 sec/hour ÷ 1,000 W/kW.

Note that the volts and amps written on the plug pack represent the **maximum possible** power draw of the device. The "idle" power usage is usually **substantially less**. You can measure this with a plug-in power meter (avail for $30 in stores.)

[image]

Comment: I hate myself for taking W for Watts.

Comment: Not that I asked it in my question but because you brought up that plug-in, can you add details about how it works? I am interested in theory so wiki link would work.

Comment: The plug-in meter measures current and voltage, and multiplies them together to calculate watts. Many such measurements are added up over time to give kilowatt-hours. There is some further complexity in accounting for power factor, but that warrants a separate question and explanation.